# actual and formal argument lists differ in length > "%d", variable

Tags: java

I was getting this error, and I actually did fix it but I want to understand why it works.
Here's my code:

```
class GuessGame{
    public void startGame(){
        Player p1 = new Player();
        Player p2 = new Player();
        Player p3 = new Player();
        int secretNumber = (int) (Math.random() * 10);
        while (true){
            //int p1Guess = p1.guess();
            //p2Guess = p2.guess();
            //p3Guess = p3.guess();
            if (p1.guess() == secretNumber){
                System.out.println("Player 1 got it right! %d", secretNumber);  
                break;
            } else if (p2.guess() == secretNumber){
                System.out.println("Player 2 got it right! %d", secretNumber);  
                break;
            } else if (p3.guess() == secretNumber){
                System.out.println("Player 3 got it right! %d", secretNumber);
                break;
            }
        }

    }
}


class Player{
    int number = 0;
    public int guess(){
        number = (int) (Math.random() * 10);
        System.out.println("I'm guessing %d!", number);
        return number;
    }
}

class GameLauncher{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        GuessGame starting = new GuessGame();
        starting.startGame();
    }
}
```

So, if I change all the `%d` to `" stuff " + variable` it stops giving me the error.
All the posts I found online for this error has to do with constructor, that's why I'm asking as I don't need any for this (I shouldn't use any for this exercise)

Comment: `printf` is what you want.

Comment: Ohhh I think I know.

Comment: @aristotll I'll read the stuff about println and printf, you should give it an answer so I can choose yours

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `println` only takes one or zero argument.

[image]

About format string input, use [`java.io.PrintStream#printf(java.lang.String, java.lang.Object...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#printf-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Use the method System.out.printf("Some Test %s","String");